# How can I detect non-western characters?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

I want to disallow certain UTF-8 input (server-side), e.g. eastern languages, where example input might be " 伊 ".

However, I do want to continue supporting other latin or "latin-like" characters, such as the welsh ŵ and ŷ, so [checking against latin-1 is not possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Coverage).

What are my options? (if language specific, PHP preferred)

Thanks very much.

---

Reasoning: browser support for a lot of non-western characters is often missing (e.g. on a different browser I just see a box in the question above), so for things like display names sometimes it's appropriate to restrict it even if it's not appropriate for message bodies

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you don't want to allow some languages on an internationalized site?

Comment: Fair question. It's just necessary for one field of a table; the rest of the website will support it.

Comment: So what is the subset of characters you're allowing? Does it fit an existing character set? If so, you can just `iconv` the string to the target encoding, discarding all invalid characters.

Comment: browser support for a lot of non-western characters is often missing (e.g. on a different browser I just see a box in the question above), so for things like display names sometimes it's appropriate to restrict it even if it's not appropriate for message bodies

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just do

```
preg_match('/[^\\p{Common}\\p{Latin}]/u', $string)
```

where `$string` is an UTF-8 string. This will return "1" if there are non-latin characters and will return "0" otherwise.

Example:

```
var_dump(preg_match('/[^\\p{Common}\\p{Latin}]/u', 'sf..ŷaás??'));  //int(0)
var_dump(preg_match('/[^\\p{Common}\\p{Latin}]/u', 'sf..ŷݤaás??')); //int(1)
```

Comment: Is there a list of named subpatterns anywhere?