# PHP: Check alphabetic characters from any latin-based language?

Tags: php, regex, internationalization, locale

Using PHP I want to check that a string **contains only alphabetic characters** (I do not want to allow any numerals or special characters like !@#$%^&*). `ctype_alpha()` would seem great for this purpose.

**The problem is that I want to allow accented letters, such as found in French, etc. For example, I want to allow "Lórien".**

I know that `ctype_alpha()` can be used with `set_locale()`, but that still seems too limited for this use case, since I want to allow characters from all latin-based languages.

Any ideas how best to accomplish this?

---

Note: The solution posted at [How can I detect non-western characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411566/how-can-i-detect-non-western-characters) is great for explicitly detecting non-Latin characters, but it allows special characters and white space, which I do not want to allow:

`preg_match('/[^\\p{Common}\\p{Latin}]/u', $string)`

I want something that would work like this, but limit the allowed characters to ***alphabetic characters*** (so no special characters like !@#$%^&).

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411566/how-can-i-detect-non-western-characters) help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this regex:

```
^\p{Latin}+$
```

Working regex example:

https://regex101.com/r/I5b2mC/1

Comment: Is A-z already contained in \p{Latin}? Don't know, just wondering.

Comment: Beautiful. This is exactly what I needed. And indeed, `^[\p{Latin}]+$` seems to work just as well... I had no idea that the solution was so simple...

Comment: Also in my case it was essential to use the /u (unicode) flag to properly handle UTF-8 encoding. Otherwise it (sometimes) breaks inexplicably and it's really easy to forget about this flag.

Answer (score 3):

This might work

```
 [^\P{latin}\s\p{Punctuation}]
```

Its all latin, but not punctuation nor whitespace.
where `\P` means NOT this property
and `\p` means this property.

Put it in a negative class its

*NOT, NOT* Latin = Include All Latin
*NOT* Punctuation = Exclude Punctuation
*NOT* Whitespace = Exclude Whitespace

Comment: It turns out that `^[\p{Latin}]+$` is really all that's needed here... but thanks for this.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know if Latin included punctuation and whitespac, guess not.