# PHP: Check for characters in the Latin script plus spaces and numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am new to regex and I have been going round and round on this problem.

[PHP: Check alphabetic characters from any latin-based language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21633769/3198356) gives the brilliant regex to check for any characters in the Latin script, which is part of what I need.

```
^\p{Latin}+$
```

and provides a working example at https://regex101.com/r/I5b2mC/1

If I use the regex in PHP by using

```
echo preg_match('/^\p{Latin}+$/', $testString);
```

and `$testString` contains only Latin letters, the output will be `1`.  If there is any non-Latin letters, the output will be `0`. Brilliant.

To add numbers in I tried `^\p{Latin}+[[:alnum:]]*$` but that allows any characters in the Latin script **OR** non-Latin letters **and** numbers (letters without accents — grave, acute, cedilla, umlaut etc.) as it is the equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

If you add any numbers with characters in the Latin script, `echo preg_match('/^\p{Latin}+[[:alnum:]]*$/', $testString);` returns a `0`.  All numbers return a `0` too. This can be confirmed by editing the expression in https://regex101.com/r/I5b2mC/1

How do I edit the expression in `echo preg_match('/^\p{Latin}+$/', $testString);` to output a `1` if there are any characters in the Latin script, any numbers and/or spaces in `$testString`?  For example, I wish for a `1` to be output if `$testString` is `Café ßüs 459`.

Comment: Use `preg_match('/^[\p{Latin}\s\d]+$/u', $testString)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two things to change:

- Add `u` flag to support chars other than ASCII (`/^\p{Latin}+$/` => `/^[\p{Latin}]+$/u`)
- Create a character class for letters, digits and whitespace patterns (`/^\p{Latin}+$/u` => `^[\p{Latin}]+$/u`)
- Then add the digit and whitespace patterns. If you need to support any Unicode digits, add `\d`. If you need to support only ASCII digits, add `0-9`.

Thus, you can use

```php
preg_match('/^[\p{Latin}\s0-9]+$/u', $testString) // ASCII only digits
preg_match('/^[\p{Latin}\s\d]+$/u', $testString)  // Any digits
```

Also, `\s` with `u` flag will match any Unicode whitespace chars.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, it is possible to prohibit any string containing letters that are not Latin (without to add one by one characters or groups of characters you want to allow):

```
$re = '~ ^ (?! .* [^\PL\p{Latin}] ) .+ $ ~mux';
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/7fcVG6#v8.1.5)

If you want strings with at least one Latin letter (and no letters from other alphabets), you can use a *[script run](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC22)* to build your pattern:

```
$re = '~ ^ [^\pL\r\n]* (?= \p{Latin} ) (*sr: .+ ) $ ~mux';
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/8WVkt#v8.1.5)

These two solutions may be more flexible. Obviously it all depends on the goal.

More about *script runs* [here](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2unicode.html#scriptruns).